# Using Timer in a stateless EJB method to time out long-running operation

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, stateless-session-bean

I have a Stateless EJB containing various methods and I would like to use a timer in a function so that if the method takes longer than say 30 seconds, a timeout will occur and the caller will be notified.

I have looked at the `@Schedule` annotation for EJB Methods but I don't think that can serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way, if you don't need precision, is to invoke a method marked as `@Asynchronous` with a `Future` in its signature that will send a notification after 30 seconds.

The method has to be on another EJB for the `@Asynchronous` to be working.

Then from the caller, if the elapsed time is shorter than 30 seconds, you can cancel the operation.